# Is this possible to run one application on different Java version ( JDK 1.8 and JDK 12 )?

Tags: java, spring-boot, paytm

We are developing web application with payment gateway ( Spring Boot, Paytm ).

We are using JDK 12 for our REST application. In our application we integrate Paytm payment gateway. If we are running our project on JDK 12 then everything is working fine except payment gateway. If I downgrade my JDK version to JDK 1.8 then all is working well. But I don't want to downgrade my JDK.

Is it possible to run part of the code in JDK 1.8 and other in JDK 12?
If yes then how?

Comment: I suppose that you are using some container, f.e: Tomcat. In the container you can run as many WARs as you want and each WAR can have a different JAVA version as far as I know. I suppose that you cannot mix in a WAR.

Comment: @vmrvictor I am not aware of the option to specify different JRE for each WAR in Tomcat. Nevertheless it doesn't matter, if you have two WARs then you can always have two Tomcats too.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. One Java application can run only on one Java version.

If you really don't want to downgrade to Java 8 then your only option is to split your application into two and make these applications communicate via some kind of API.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for one JVM (and hence one web container) to run two versions of Java at the same time.

Here are some of your options:

- Run two separate web containers (JVMs) and have them communicate via an internal API.  That could be a lot of extra work.
- Downgrade your dev work to Java 8.  That could also be a lot of work, or worse.  (You might have dependencies that are only available for Java 11+.)
- Try Java 11 instead of Java 8.  Reasoning:

  - Java 12 is not an LTS version of Java, but Java 11 is.  Therefore it is more likely that the Paytm gateway software will run on Java 11.
  - The difference between Java 11 and 12 for your application is not that great.  Looking at the summary of new features in Java 12, there doesn't look to be anything that you couldn't do without ... until the next Java LTS release.
- Figure out why the Paytm integration doesn't work in a later version of Java.  On the Github site where the distribute the JAR files, it is implied that the "Java Kit 8" version supports Java 8 *and later versions*.

  The problem might related to SSL support in later versions of Java.  Maybe you need to force Java 12 to use an older TLS version to match what the remote gateway service is expecting.

  There may be clues in your log files; e.g. log messages, stack traces.
- Aoid using the problematic (?) Java binding, and change your Java code to talk directly to the Paytm Web API, using HttpClient or similar.  (In fact, trying to see if you can do this from a Java 11 / 12 JVM *may* help you work out what the problem with the Java binding binding is; e.g. if this is a SSL problem.
- Contact Paytm support ....
- Look for an alternative to Paytm with better support for Java 11 / 12